# связи таблиц Sqlite

Tags: c, база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3

Есть 3 таблицы `Report`, `Recipe`, `Operator`. В таблице `Report` есть калонка `Recipe/Operator` которая долна иметь связь с соответствующими таблицами.
Пробовал создавать связь так, но ничего не выходит и калонка `Recipe/Operator` просто хранит `NULL`. А таблица Recipe(пример создания которой ниже) вообще не создается.Обьясните как создать такую связь?

```
char *sql = sqlite3_mprintf(
             "CREATE TABLE '%q'(" \
             "'%q'   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," \
             "'%q'   INT," \
             "'%q'   INT," \
             "'%q'   INT," \
             "'%q'   INT," \
             "'%q'   INT," \
             "'%q'   INT," \
             "'%q'   INT," \
             "'%q'   REAL," \
             "'%q'   REAL," \
             "'%q'   REAL," \
             "'%q'   REAL," \
             "'%q'   INT," \
             "'%q'   INT," \
             "FOREIGN KEY(TITLE) REFERENCES report_table(ID));"
            , tableName
            , SCHEME_RECIPE_ID
            , SCHEME_RECIPE_TITLE
            , SCHEME_RECIPE_FRACTION_1
            , SCHEME_RECIPE_FRACTION_2
            , SCHEME_RECIPE_FRACTION_3
            , SCHEME_RECIPE_FRACTION_4
            , SCHEME_RECIPE_FRACTION_5
            , SCHEME_RECIPE_FRACTION_6
            , SCHEME_RECIPE_BITUMEN
            , SCHEME_RECIPE_MP
            , SCHEME_RECIPE_CELLULOSE_1
            , SCHEME_RECIPE_CELLULOSE_2
            , SCHEME_RECIPE_DUST);

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
```

Comment: Любая колонка (кроме автоинкрементного id) хранит NULL если ей явно не задать какое либо значение. Создание связи таблиц не говорит о том, что какие то значения будут появляться автоматически. Вам следует самому устанавливать верные значения для такой колонки

Comment: Вы задаёте FK (title), однако в создаваемой структуре таблицы такого поля тупо не видать.

Comment: @Mike, каким образом это сделать?что бы калонка Recipe/Operator хранила одно из калонок Name из соотв. таблиц?

Comment: Ну во первых хранить все таки стоит id, а не имя. Делаете foraign, его назначение только _проверить_ что вы внесли корректное значение. А при использовании эта колонка ничем не отличается от остальных. Сначала получаете требуемый id из таблицы например Recipe, а потом сами его явно указываете при insert/update. И одна колонка не может ссылаться на две разные таблицы, если сущности в этих таблицах подобны стоит задуматься о объединении их в одну таблицу или создание дополнительной таблицы, содержащей оба вида сущностей